# In python, do you have to create dummy variables to train a model such as RandomForests?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can you not just use categorical variables like in R where you can feed factor variables into the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support is not there in `scikit-learn` (yet), no.  Other python packages for tree models do support categorical variables though, e.g. `H2O`'s tree models and `LightGBM` (and in a different way, `CatBoost`).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I would like to ask a follow up question: Sometimes I see people encoding categorical variables in indexes, such as the infamous labeencoder function. Like they would have 7 variables and assign each value to a number from 1 to 7. Is this an afficent method? Does it matter if I use this method or one hot encoding? My understanding is that the aforementioned label encoding method should not be very efficient because when training the model the algorithm would try to identify a linear trend when it's just a case of either or. I'm quite new to all of this.

Comment: See e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/78052/55122

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any solution to avoid one-hot-encoding/ordinal encoding. But it is very simple:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoded_df = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False).fit(feature_df)
```

feature_df can be a pd.DataFrame or a np.ndarray containing your categorical features.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I asked the question mostly out of curiosity. I've recently started learning python and the associated packages, going into it I thought most things would be pretty similar with R except for the syntax. This particular issue just left me curious for some reason.